# How to work out TFS uri and location for currently loaded solution projects in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, envdte, visual-studio-sdk

I am trying to work out how, in my Visual Studio Extension, I can work out which of the currently loaded projects are in TFS and then the TFS server uri and location for each of these projects.

I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
foreach (EnvDTE.Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
{
    if (project.IsInTFS) {   
        var uri = project.TFSUri;             // http://tfsserver:8080/tfs
        var location = project.TFSLocation;   // $\TeamProject\Project
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`SourceControl2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/EnvDTE80.SourceControl2.aspx) interface to accomplish this in the following way:

```cs
foreach (Project project in dte.Solution.Projects)
{
    if (dte.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(project.FileName))
    {
        var bindings = project.GetSourceControlBindings();
        var uri = bindings.ServerName;             
        var location = bindings.ServerBinding;
        // your logic goes here
    }
}
```

Where `GetSourceControlBindings` is an extension method:

```cs
public static SourceControlBindings GetSourceControlBindings(this Project project)
{
    SourceControl2 sourceControl = (SourceControl2)project.DTE.SourceControl;
    return sourceControl.GetBindings(project.FullName);
}
```

**Note**: you will have to a add reference to the *EnvDTE80.dll* assembly.

---

If you're interested exclusively in TFS source control, then you should add one more condition:

```cs
if (bindings.ProviderName == "{4CA58AB2-18FA-4F8D-95D4-32DDF27D184C}")
```

Where that magic guid specifies the Team Foundation Source Control Provider.

Comment: Brilliant! Much appreciated Yuriy!!

Comment: Oh, one small point, I think you need to do dte.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(project.FullName), rather than dte.SourceControl.IsItemUnderSCC(project.FileName)